# Is there a special use of left curly brace { regex?

Tags: java, regex

I need to escape a left curly brace but not a right curly brace in my java regex.

My question is what's special about the left curly brace? Is it similar to say a normal bracket  ( where the bracket is used for another purpose in regex (ie a group)? If so please share an example of the use case.

Why do I only need to escape left but not right curly brace?

Comment: `{` and `}` is used to specify multipliers, EG `{1,3}` means 1 to 3 of the previous token...

Comment: See: https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of repetition is `{min,max}`. `a{1,3}` matches `a`, `aa` or `aaa`. If you don't escape the `{` it will be interpreted as a start of a repetition group that should be matched with a closing `}`.